# Tcl's snack returns garbage list of mixer inputs

Tags: audio, tcl, toolkit

```
package require sound
foreach jack [snack::mixer inputs] {
  puts $jack
}
```

I expected to get a list with identifiers like Line1, Mic, etc, but I get the following garbage:

```
Ðnf
```

I wanted to build a dropbox list to choose a mixer input to record from. I am on Linux, using Tcl 8.6 and snack extension 2.2.10.

Am **I** doing something wrong or this is a bug I should report upstream?

Comment: Snack hasn't been updated since 2005.  You may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar using *snack* version 2.2 with *Tcl/Tk* version 8.6.

But is used the following code:

```
package require snack

set inputList [audio inputDevice]
```

The result is a list of input devices name that I could set with:

```
audio selectInput [lindex $inputList $idx]
```

This is part of a multi platform software that works on Linux too.

Of course you could use *snack::audio* to have a better qualified name.

Comment: I get a list of default plughw:0 plughw:1 plughw:2. Not very informative, but plughw:0 is my usb headset mic, plughw:2 my internal soundcard mic, plughw:1 does not work. Anyway I can now set the recording source.